# Assign Json values stored in a string to class values then store in SQL

Tags: c#, json

I have  JSON object received from a website and store it in a string value.I have generated the necessary classes to map to the JSON obejct.My question is how then do I get to assign the value of JSON to the class properties/variables

JSON data:

```
{
    "echo_req": {
        "subscribe": 1,
        "transaction": 1
    },
    "msg_type": "transaction",
    "transaction": {
        "action": "buy",
        "amount": "-250.0000",
        "balance": "530800.61",
        "contract_id": "108 32430388",
        "currency": "USD",
        "date_expiry": 1478242335,
        " display_name": "Volatility 10 Index",
        "id": "de7cc6e6-218c-86a5-805f-093c1176f605",
        "longcode": "Win payout if Volatility 10 Index is strictly lower than entry spot at 15 minutes after contract start time.",
        "symbol": "R_10",
        "transaction_id": "215802164 88",
        "transaction_time": 1478241435
    }
}
```

C# class:

```
namespace BinaryData
 {

    public class Echo_Req
    {
        public int subscribe { get; set; }
        public int transaction { get; set; }
    }
    public class Transaction
    {
        public string action { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string balance { get; set; }
        public string contract_id { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public int date_expiry { get; set; }
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string longcode { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public int transaction_time { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Echo_Req echo_req { get; set; }
        public string msg_type { get; set; }
        public Transaction transaction { get; set; }
    }

}
```

In program I have but getting stuck in how i assign the contract ID

```
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);//
Console.WriteLine(str);//prints json correctly

Transaction tradeDetails = new Transaction();
tradeDetails.contract_id=str.contract_id//How do I do this
```

Also just a side note would this be the effective way of getting the values to write the code to store in SQL.I will be using ADO.NET  becasue simply  dont know EF yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize JSON string into objects.

In Your case:

```
Rootobject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str);
```

Then

```
tradeDetails.contract_id = ro.transaction.contract_id
```

And in your JSON is glitch

`" display_name"` - should be `"display_name"` - I think this is typo error.